# Is there any way to get the value of multiplecheckboxes that the rendering in for loop with django-template-language

Tags: python, django

How to get value of mutiplecheckboxes in django.

the below code showing the groups at frontend

```
{% for group in groups %}
  <tr><td>{{group.name}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="superuser" id="group-{{group.id}}" value="{{group.id}}"></td>                                             
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

I want to get the values of all checked boxes at backend when I submit the record.

[image: frontend]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

here is a way that i used and worked, try this may help you :)

in your html file:

```
{% for group in groups %}
  <tr><td>{{group.name}}</td>
  <td><input type="checkbox" name="superuser[]" id="group-{{group.id}}" value="{{group.id}}"></td>                                             
 </tr>
{% endfor %}
```

and in your view:

```
checked_group=request.POST.getlist('superuser[]')
```

so the **checked_group** will be a list contains all checked group ids.

Comment: Yes I got the list, Thank you so much bro ❤️

Comment: @ShubhamNagar Great! you can check the answer to help others with the same question :)